# Python: how to invert list membership check based on boolean variable?

Tags: python, list, membership

How can a check for list membership be inverted based on a boolean variable?

I am looking for a way to simplify the following code:

```python
#  variables: `is_allowed:boolean`, `action:string` and `allowed_actions:list of strings`

if is_allowed:
    if action not in allowed_actions:
        print(r'{action} must be allowed!')

else:
    if action in allowed_actions:
        print(r'{action} must NOT be allowed!')
```

I feel there must be a way to avoid doing the check twice, once for `in` and another time for `not in`, but can't figure out a less verbose way.

Comment: only check if is allowed if action is in allowed actions and put it on one line.. given the constraints and not knowing the rest of the code you have to check twice but only if the action is in the list due to short circuit...but meh i guess that’s the same as what you got ...

Comment: Your code will never execute the check twice in any one execution, so it's difficult to see what you could 'improve'. Shorter in lines is not necessarily better, in fact can increase difficulty of comprehension.

Comment: @barny: I was assuming that maybe I was not aware of some specific python idiom that could be used in this kind of scenario.

Comment: I'm a strong advocate of 'keep it simple' - e.g. one-liners can be difficult to understand/maintain/debug. Kindall's answer is, after all, shorter in lines, but not so short in time to understand if you had the job of maintaining it.

Comment: totally agree! but it looked 'wrong' to me, ie too verbose and clunky, so I assumed there must be a simpler and cleaner way to approach it

Comment: That's the thing: verbose is not necessarily bad if it's simple and clear.

Comment: I go for verbose when it is intended and planned; but it is also good to know what the options are; knifes are inherently unsafe but they can still be super useful.

Comment: Big picture: Why do we have an "is_allowed" variable when we have a list of allowed actions and the selected action?

Comment: So are, err, bazookas. Not sure what your point is. Got to break eggs to make an omelette. Any more cliches? Yes it's horses for courses. But there are flat courses and hilly courses.

Comment: `allowed_actions` is bad naming, should probably be `all_actions` or just `actions`

Comment: regarding the knives and bazookas I don't have a point; I just want to know what exists out there; whether using them is justified in a specific scenario is a different question entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the result of the test to `is_allowed`. Then use `is_allowed` to put together the correct error message.

```
if (action in allowed_actions) != is_allowed:
    print(action, "must" if is_allowed else "must NOT", "be allowed!")
```

Comment: Yeah, but. How long would it take to work out what this is doing if you came across it cold?

Comment: In my experience, this is a reasonably common idiom when dealing with Boolean options, for example checkboxes in a GUI, that reverse some behavior.

Comment: It might be easier to follow if you used `xor` (`from operator import xor`) instead of `!=`.  They're the same, but `xor` is a lot easier to parse if you're not familiar with the not-equal-to trick.

Comment: It's a fair critique that other ways of writing it might be more readable, but I've seen plenty of code like this. Better variable names would help a lot, probably.

Comment: Yes the variable names are not helping at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way your specific code is structured, I think the only improvement you can make is to just store `action in allowed_actions` in a variable:

```
present = action in allowed_actions
if is_allowed:
    if not present:
        print(r'{action} must be allowed!')

else:
    if present:
        print(r'{action} must NOT be allowed!')
```